# Einstein propulsion system

Tags: special-relativity, gravity, field-theory, propulsion, warp-drives

Will an extended body(cylinder) with asymmetric energy distribution across its H axis experience free-fall(geodesic)acceleration in free space(outside of any influences) in vacuum because of the time dilation differential between the top and the bottom?Just like an extended body in gravitational field will experience free-fall acceleration because the time passes differently on the top (further from the field source) and the bottom.If so how much energy(joules) will it take to generate 1g constant free-fall acceleration in vacuum in free space using asymmetric energy distribution across 25cm long,1kg cylinder?

Answer (score 4):

> Will an extended body(cylinder) with asymmetric energy distribution along its H axis experience free-fall motion in free space(outside of any influences) in vacuum because of the time dilation differential between the top and the bottom.

No. An extended body will not randomly accelerate in free space, regardless of any asymmetry in its energy distribution. Without any outside influence, its center of momentum will have a constant velocity as measured by any distant observer in the surrounding asymptotically flat spacetime.